# PHP MySQLi prepared statements and fetching subset of columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using MySQLi and PHP to call a stored MySQL routine with prepared statements. It returns a result set with dozens of columns.

```
$stmt = $dbconnection->prepare("CALL SomebodysDbProcedure(?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $idvalue);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, ...);
```

However, I am only interested in *a subset* of the output columns.

[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) says `bind_result()` is required to handle the *complete set* of returned columns:

> Note that all columns must be bound after `mysqli_stmt_execute()` and
>   prior to calling `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`.

Do I need to add code also for those columns I'm uninterested in? If so the application will break if the MySQL stored routine result set is expanded in the future, or even columns rearranged. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you just don't want to write out all those variables for the bind_result() function. You could use a function like below instead of the bind_result() function. Pass it your $stmt object and you'll get back an array of standard objects with the fields you want.

```
function getResult($stmt)
{
    $valid_fields = array('title', 'date_created'); // enter field names you care about

    if (is_a($stmt, 'MySQLi_STMT')) {
        $result = array();

        $metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $fields = $metadata->fetch_fields();

        for (; ;)
        {
            $pointers = array();
            $row = new \stdClass();

            $pointers[] = $stmt;
            foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
                if (in_array($field->name, $valid_fields)) {
                    $fieldname = $field->name;
                    $pointers[] = &$row->$fieldname;
                }
            }

            call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_result', $pointers);

            if (!$stmt->fetch())
                break;

            $result[] = $row;
        }

        $metadata->free();

        return $result;
    }
    return array();
}
```

Comment: Seems promising. As you say, the function returns an array of `stdClass` objects. But how do I access the fields within a `stdClass` object (for instance the field `date_created`)?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `in_array($field->name, $valid_fields)` and `$row = new stdClass();`?

Comment: you're right on the $field->name part. I updated. You can access the fields as properties of the object. so you get back an array of objects called $row. To get the title field $row->title;

Comment: I see the fields now, but they're all null. May be something I'm doing wrong. BTW, I got a similar solution to work (see below).

Comment: awesome. ok, well I guess you're good to go then. how's about a "mark correct" for me? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Jonathan Mayhak guided me in the right direction. On PHP [bind_result page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), nieprzeklinaj provides a function called `fetch()`. It works; use it like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL SomebodysDbProcedure(?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $idvalue);
$stmt->execute();
$sw = (array)(fetch($stmt));
$s = $sw[0]; // Get first row
$dateCreated = $s['date_created']; // Get field date_created
```

**Edit:** Unfortunately successive calls within the same PHP file don't seem to work with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fetch_fields php method:

```
array mysqli_fetch_fields ( mysqli_result $result )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Comment: Isn't this approach based on `$mysqli->query`? It doesn't seem to involve prepared statements.