# Successive MySQLi prepared statements not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to make successive calls to MySQL stored routines (using prepared statements) from the same PHP file, like this:

```
$conn = getconn();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL GetUserLoginData(?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();

// Process data here... until next stored routine call

$conn = getconn();
// var_dump($conn);
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("CALL SetUserLoginTime(?);");
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $userid);
$stmt2->execute();
```

where `getconn()` returns a database connection with `new mysqli()`.

This code works on a web server running PHP 5.3.8-1/MySQL 5.1.54, but *not* on a server with PHP 5.3.10/5.5.29.

If I uncomment `var_dump($conn)` I get  `["error"]=> string(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"`.

I can't figure out why this is happening on just one server.

Comment: Why do you need several connections to the same database? Just reuse `$conn`.

Comment: @TillHelge: True. My function `getconn()` caches the connection though. I removed the second `$conn = getconn()`, still got the same error.

Comment: As documentation said: you have to free your result (first $stmt): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: Duplicate of 1000s. Easily searchable by error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$conn = getconn();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL GetUserLoginData(?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();

// Process data here... until next stored routine call

$conn = getconn();
// var_dump($conn);
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("CALL SetUserLoginTime(?);");
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $userid);
$stmt2->execute();
```

Because prepared statements use an unbuffered query type. You have two options:

1) Close your query after executions

```
$conn = getconn();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL GetUserLoginData(?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close(); // Frees the buffer
```

2) Use free_results: 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

*Scenario Not Within Your Question:*

Sometimes Closing the query or freeing the results is not an option. For example a `while` loop... In A Situation like this, you should use:

```
store_result();
```

Comment: `$stmt->close();` doesn't work for me, still "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now". I assume the processing of data from `$stmt` is supposed to happen before the `close()`. I'll try the second option.

Comment: After hours of testing, I've concluded that the error is down to the fetching of subset data:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014602/php-mysqli-prepared-statements-and-fetching-subset-of-columns I have no idea how this can be. Otherwise you were right about the close part.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$conn = getconn();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL GetUserLoginData(?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();

// Process data here... until next stored routine call

mysqli_free_result();
$conn = getconn();
// var_dump($conn);
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("CALL SetUserLoginTime(?);");
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $userid);
$stmt2->execute();
```

Comment: Whats  the difference between your code and the ops code? Why should he use the changes you have made?

Comment: I have used mysqli_free_result(); to free the previous result

Comment: Perhaps make the clearer. the OP is obviously confused about this error message, and just reading a block of code is not explaining anything.

Comment: @Gautam3164: The error log says `mysqli_free_result() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given`.

Comment: @Gruber Don't mean to shine mine higher than this.. But try closing your prepared statements when your finished with them, see my answer for an example

Comment: Any reason to down it..??

Answer (score -1):

Before making the second database call, call the PHP function `clearStoredResults($conn)` as defined below (where `$conn` is the MySQLi database link obtained by calling `new mysqli(...);`):

```
function clearStoredResults($mysqli_link) {
    while ($mysqli_link->next_result()) {
        if ($l_result = $mysqli_link->store_result()) {
            $l_result->free();
        }
    }
}
```

I've found this makes it possible to make successive calls.